# WooCommerce Memberships: Conditional Restricted Content Check

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, woocommerce-memberships

I'm trying to make a menu of pages links that people can access once they have purchased a membership (through [WooCommerce Memberships](https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/memberships/)). I want for that pages to be greyed out, if they don't yet have access to them.

I've set the pages to gain access X days after purchase in WooCommerce Memberships, however the code I am using is simply not working. It is returning false even when it should return true.

Any ideas?

```
<?php 
     $restrict_th0 = wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted(24);
     $restrict_th1 = wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted(28);
     $restrict_th2 = wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted(30);
?>

<ul id="menu-academy">
     <li>
     <?php if ( $restrict_th0 ) { } else { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/URL HERE/">
     <?php } ?>
     <span class="module_no">0</span><span class="module_descript">MODULE DESCRIPTION<span class="module_access<?php if ( $restrict_th0 ) { ?> lock<?php } ?>">
     <i class="fa fa-2x fa-<?php if ( $restrict_th0 ) { } else { ?>un<?php } ?>lock<?php if ( $restrict_th0 ) { } else { ?>-alt<?php } ?>" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span><?php if ( $restrict_th0 ) { } else { ?></a><?php } ?></li>

</ul
```

Comment: Those first few lines are the post IDs (ie. check if "Page ID 24" is restricted, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use this conditional :

```
if( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $membership_plan ) ) {
   // Displayed fully functional Menu
} else {
   // Greyed displayed inactive Menu
}
```

This works for active logged user that have subscribed to a plan and which subscription is valid.

`$membership_plan` has to be replaced by a membership plan slug, post object or related post ID.

After you can use also `wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted(ID)` or `is_page(ID)` for furthers actions…